# Traduction de l'expression "Doing something piecemeal" en français

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

Un ancien collègue m'a fait lire récemment un document dans lequel il était dit du système d'information sur lequel il travaille :

> The system, however, was designed piecemeal.

Le [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piecemeal) donne cette définition:

> piecemeal: one piece at a time, gradually

Après quelques recherches sur internet, je n'ai pas réussi à déterminer si ceci voulait dire:

> Ce système, cependant, à été conçu graduellement, par étapes.

Ou bien:

> Ce système, cependant, à été conçu de façon empirique, voire "à l'arrache".

Ce qui ne signifie pas tout à fait la même chose: dans les deux cas on y trouve l'idée d'approche par étapes, mais alors que la première proposition fait état d'une démarche structurée, positive, la seconde est plutôt péjorative et fait état d'une absence de démarche structurée, d'un produit qui se construit "comme il le peut".

Le reste du document est relativement neutre à l'égard du système en question et le décrit de façon factuelle. Le *however* que j'ai cité suit un paragraphe expliquant que le système à maintenant plusieurs années d'exploitation derrière lui et que le construire a représenté une charge de travail assez conséquente.

D'après vous, l'une des deux interprétations que je propose plus-haut est-elle la bonne ?  Ou bien est-ce encore autre chose ?

Comment: Cette question porte sur le sens d'une expression anglaise. Ça me parait limite “off-topic”, sinon “borderline”. Elle a plus sa place sur [english.se]. Par principe, je vote pour la fermer tant qu'elle n'est pas tournée autrement.

Comment: Un traduction *depuis* anglais est off-topic sur EL&U.  Je crois que c'est acceptable sur ce site.

Comment: Bonjour. Désolé si c'est effectivement off-topic, il s'agirait en ce cas d'une maladresse de ma part. Pouvez-vous statuer sur ce point et me laisser un commentaire ici ? Je supprimerai cette question moi-même, le cas échéant.

Comment: À relire ta question, je suis d'accord avec @Stéphane.  Tu sembles plus intéressé par le sens de l'expression anglaise que par comment l'exprimer en français: une explication du sens sans traduction te conviendrait. À comparer avec les autres [tag:traduction] où les questionneurs sont capables de donner le sens précis qu'ils cherchent à exprimer.

Comment: Que je sois clair : cette question m’intéresse. Le problème que j'y trouve, c'est que ça ouvre la porte à : « Qu'est ce que ça veut dire “wipe slime from his mother’s boots” en français ? » alors que la réponse se trouve sur EL&U.

Comment: Oui oui, je comprends bien, et il n'y a aucun souci. Le sens de cette question, c'est effectivement : "cette expression anglaise, que veut-elle dire en français ? Comment l'interpréter, et comment la dire, aussi, pour en respecter le sens ?". Si elle devait être off-topic, cela ne me poserait pas de souci, mais je préfèrerais la clôturer par moi même tant qu'à faire (si c'est possible).

Comment: Dans tous les cas ne la supprime pas, il faut qu'elle serve de sujet de discussion, et peut-être d'exemple. Et personne ne t'en veux ;-)

Comment: Ok, je la garde ouverte, promis ! S'il y a un meta qui s'ouvre, pourras-tu me le dire ? Car indépendamment de la question posée ici, je trouve la question de son admissibilité intéressante.

Comment: (et je sais bien ;) Mais merci !)

Comment: Pour moi, la question est quand mêm fort axée sur la recherche d'une traduction. Je n'y vois aucun problème, à part que je ne connais pas la réponse. Quelqu'un a pensé à vérifier si l'expression _à l'emporte-pièces_ pourrait convenir?

Comment: « À l'emporte-pièce » veut dire « hâtivement, trop rapidement », et ne convient donc pas du tout…

Comment: Si j'ose rallonger encore la discussion, je pense que c'est un exemple d'une question intéressante: il faut parfois décortiquer complètement une expression pour pouvoir trouver une traduction adéquate.

Comment: C'est une question tout à fait on-topic pour FL&U. Ici le problème n'est pas réellement la signification de la phrase anglaise, mais comment préserver au mieux cette signification en français.

Comment: Cette question est hors-sujet telle qu'elle est rédigée : elle ne parle que de l'expression anglaise, il n'y a aucun lien avec le français. [Que faire des questions qui ne parlent pas du français ? What to do about questions that are not about French?](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/179)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La traduction directe de *piecemeal* en tant qu'adverbe serait **graduellement**, **par étape**, ou **par petits pas**. Cela se déduit du sens donné par le *New Oxford American Dictionary* :

> **piecemeal** (adjective & adverb)
>   characterized by unsystematic partial measures taken over a period of time

Cependant, dans un certain nombre de cas, *piecemeal* possède une connotation négative. On traduira alors l'adjectif par **fragmentaire**, **décousu**, et l'adverbe par *« de manière fragmentaire »*, etc.

---

En particulier, je note que ***fragmentaire*** est la traduction la plus courante pour les documents de travail de l'Union européenne ([celui-ci](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=COM:2001:0582%3aFIN%3aEN%3aPDF) par exemple). Cette traduction me plaît bien, d'ailleurs, puisqu'elle garde une partie de l'ambiguïté sur la connotation du mot : comme *piecemeal*, *fragmentaire* est a priori neutre mais s'emploie parfois avec une connotation négative.

Comment: Pour moi, c'est clair que *piecemeal* n'est jamais franchement positif, donc tire plutôt du côté négatif. De ce fait, je crois que fragmentaire (voire décousu) est le mot le plus apte. *Par étape* sous entend une progression par ordre logique, tandis que piecemeal signifie justement dans un ordre 'aléatoire' (ou organique, au mieux).

Comment: _Fragmentaire_ est bien trouvé au niveau du sens, par contre il me semble que ce n'est pas tout à fait le même niveau de langage : ce n'est pas aussi naturel que _piecemeal_ (mais je n'ai rien de mieux à proposer).

Comment: @Julien Guertault Il semble que nous n'avons pas d'équivalent aussi imagé en français. Mais le sens est bien là, et vu que "Fragmentaire" est utilisé par l'UE alors que "Piecemeal" se trouvait dans un document de travail de comex d'entreprise, on peut définir que le niveau de langage est bien le même. Puis, comme Fragmentaire et Piecemeal induisent en plus la même ambiguïté, comme le note F'x, je crois que l'on ne peut vraiment pas trouver mieux.

Comment: _Fragmentaire_ ou _décousu_ décrivent bien le résultat, mais pour moi _piecemeal_ a une implication temporelle en plus que de qualifier le résultat.  Une conception peut être fragmentaire parce qu'elle a été étalée sur le temps (et _peacemeal_ donne cette idée), ou parce que les responsabilités ont été distribuées et mal coordonnées sans qu'il n'y ait un étalement temporel (et _peacemeal_ ne serait pas employé en anglais).

Answer (score 5):

Je perçois l'idée que le système est le résultat d'une évolution, chaque étape étant raisonnable individuellement mais pouvant manquer de cohérence globale.

Je propose donc

> Ce système, cependant, à été conçu en différentes étapes indépendantes.

mais je ne vois pas d'expressions communes.

En passant, ni dans « empirique », ni dans « à l'arrache » je n'ai l'idée d'une évolution. Le premier note une conception n'ayant pas de base théorique, le second une conception précipitée, aucune des deux ne me semble le sens de « piecemeal ».

Answer (score 4):

Un [synonyme](http://thesaurus.com/browse/unsystematic) possible de piecemeal, en anglais, serait 'haphazard'. Et pour cela, [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/haphazard) propose *peu méthodique*. C'est deux mots à la place d'un, mais je crois que c'est le plus proche possible.

Answer (score 3):

Je n'arrive pas trouver de source, mais j'aurais sans doute utilisé l'expression "mille-feuille".

> Ce système, cependant, à été conçu comme un mille-feuille.

L'idée de fragmentaire n'y est pas présente car la fabrication du mille-feuille est très exigeante. En bonus, on garde la connotation culinaire.

Une autre solution pourrait-être :

> Ce système, cependant, à été conçu petit à petit.

Rien de péjoratif ici et on indique bien le caractère d'étape après étape.

Comment: Bien vu pour le mille feuille. Comme d'autre expression proposée plus haut, cela parle cependant plus du résultat que du processus.

Answer (score 2):

Il y a encore *[hétéroclite](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/h%C3%A9t%C3%A9roclite)* et *[disparate](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/disparate)* ainsi que l'expression *fait [de bric et de broc](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/de_bric_et_de_broc)* qui mettent l'accent sur le fait que le système est un assemblage de parties dissemblables, sans vraiment d'unité. L'idée d'évolution temporelle est cependant absente.

Comment: *Hétéroclite* et *disparate* mettent l'accent sur le résultat, alors que *piecemeal* met l'accent sur le processus. *De bric et de broc* est à mon avis plus proche…

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> "utilisant le système D"

Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_D), it seems to represent a similar feeling of using whatever is at hand in a MacGyver-ish fashion.

Whenever I've tried to describe a hack-ish, piecemeal solution, "System D" is usually term that I use.

> — Le système ne marche pas.  Qu'est-ce qu'on peut faire?
>   — Eh bien, utilise le système D.